# console.error:"fontFamily "layar-bahtera-regular" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync

Tags: react-native, expo

Everything was okay before I upgrade Expo SDK to 35 and I face this issue now. layar-bahtera-regular is my custom font and I used Font.loadAsync already. What is the problem?

```
  import * as Font from 'expo-font';

  state = { fontLoaded: false }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      'layar-bahtera-regular': require('../../assets/fonts/LayarBahteraDdW01Regular.ttf')
   });

  this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
```

}

Comment: Is that error coming in IOS?

Comment: Nope, in Android

Comment: can you post expo snack example?

Answer (score 1):

did you try doing this after the upgrade?

- Delete the node_modules folder
- Delete the package-lock.json file
- Run npm/yarn install

Also, you can try executing this command `expo install expo-font`

Let me know, if it helped